# What is Ruby lower_bound?

Tags: ruby

So I have just started learning Ruby and don't understand as to why everytime I run this code in the terminal the output is equal to 16. To me, it doesn't make sense and I would really like to understand the syntax correctly from an experienced Rubyist.

```
def smallest_square(lower_bound)
  i = 0
  while true
    square = i * i

    if square > lower_bound
      return square
    end

    i = i + 1
  end
end

puts(smallest_square(10))
```

Comment: Don't forget indentation, especially when posting here. It helps communicate not only program flow but intent.

Answer (score 6):

Your code finds the smallest number that when squared is *greater than* the given value. The sequence of squares is `1`, `4`, `9`, and `16`, so 16 is the first over the line.

A more Ruby way of expressing this is:

```
 def smallest_square(lower_bound)
   (1..lower_bound).map do |i|
     i ** 2
   end.find do |i|
     i >= lower_bound
   end
 end
```

The the thing is you can tackle this with simple math, no need for a loop:

```
def smallest_square(lower_bound)
  Math.sqrt(lower_bound).ceil ** 2
end
```

Where that just finds the next square at or above the square root of the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is a special keyword, its just the name of the argument the function `smallest_sqaure` takes.

While iterating it starts from 0,

```
0 * 0 = 0, which is not greater than `lower_bound` value i.e. 10, passed in from the `puts(smallest_square(10))`
1 * 1 = 1, not > 10,
2 * 2 = 4, not > 10,
3 * 3 = 9, not > 10
4 * 4 = 16, > 10
```

and so it returns 16 to the calling functions which prints 16 as the output.

Answer (score 0):

Lower bound is just a math term see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_and_lower_bounds  A normal method's argument name can be anything but it's good practice to use something that makes sense rather than using something like `x`

Let's break down your method to see what's happening:

```
def smallest_square(lower_bound) # define method and single argument name
  i = 0 # initialize an iterator starting which will count up to lower_bound
  while true # start a while loop which will run code inside until stopped
    square = i * i # square the value of i

    if square > lower_bound # when the value of square of i is > lower_bound
      return square 
    end
  # return the value of square but what may be confusing here
  # this breaks the while loop and returns the square of i and not value of i.  
  # If you changed it to `return i` that might make more sense to you.

    i = i + 1 # if we have not broken the while loop, increment i
            # i += 1 is also the preferred syntax here and is the same
  end # end of while loop
end  # end of method definition
```